# What is a getRotation in android?

Tags: android

When i was writing a code in android I found a method called get Rotation, Is get Rotation a default method that Android Studio provides? What is the need of this get Rotation method?

Comment: place your mouse pointer there and press ctrl+Q , you will see the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The **getRotation()** method returns a value depending in the orientation of the screen.

It is Android that offers this method and not Android Studio which is only an IDE for Android.

Back to **getRotation()** , 
it returns a specific value as follows:

0 - no rotation

2 - 180 degrees rotation

3 - 270 degrees rotation

1 - 90 degrees rotation

[Source Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#ROTATION_0)

Comment: Is there any source code available for this get Rotation method?